# Download file from virtual path URL asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a virtual path URL (http://xyz.com/eRoom/SPOmidrangesysdiv/EFT3%20Test%20Scorecard%20for%20Inyo.xlsx). Credentials required to brow this url.
I want to download file from url using ASP.NET C#.

Comment: Please provide c# code for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use HttpWebRequest to download file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778055/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-to-download-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
// You might require some headers to be added for authentication
client.AddHeader("header", "header"); 
byte[] data = client.DownloadData("http://xyz.com/eRoom/SPOmidrangesysdiv/EFT3%20Test%20Scorecard%20for%20Inyo.xlsx")'
```

Comment: I used following code but I am getting the exception "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized’"

WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("patpathv", "54rukN6YU", "corp");
myWebClient.DownloadFile("http://opseroom01.corp.emc.com/eRoomReq/Files/SPOmidrangesysdiv/EMC-QualityOps/0_1b2bab/08-24-2011%20Inyo%20Status.xlsx", @"C:\\TestScorecard.xlsx");

Answer (score 0):

You should use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as Asif mentioned above.  Here's it broken down to easily substitute alternate files in same base location.

```
string remoteUri = "http://xyz.com/eRoom/SPOmidrangesysdiv/";
string fileName = "EFT3%20Test%20Scorecard%20for%20Inyo.xlsx", myStringWebResource = null;
// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);
```

You can specify a directory in the second parameter of the `DownloadFile` method, just make sure your IIS user (typcially *SERVERNAME*\IUSR_*SERVERNAME*) has access to write to that directory.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have implemented code and used   {myWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xyz", "ABC", "abc");} . But I am getting Error - {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.}

Comment: @PintuYadav is the resource (a.k.a. file) something you need credentials for in order to access?  In other words, if you were navigating straight from a browser?  If not, try setting UseDefaultCredentials to true, possibly like this `WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient () { UseDefaultCredentials=true };`

Comment: I used following code but I am getting the exception "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized’"

WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("patpathv", "54rukN6YU", "corp");
myWebClient.DownloadFile("http://opseroom01.corp.emc.com/eRoomReq/Files/SPOmidrangesysdiv/EMC-QualityOps/0_1b2bab/08-24-2011%20Inyo%20Status.xlsx", @"C:\\TestScorecard.xlsx");